# ¿ Por qué no me deja usar BottomBar?

Tags: java, android, bottombar

Mi **gradle** app:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.prueba.hola.hola"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
```

Donde pone "23" ponía "24" pero lo he cambiado porque el **SDK** de android del 23 está completo y uso ese. ¿Qué hago para poder usar `BottomBar`?

Comment: ¿Te da algún error?

Comment: En el MainActivity, me sale en rojo cuando declaro: BottomBar mBottomBar;

Comment: No veo que exista ningún elemento que se llame BottomBar para Android.

Comment: Hay un video en youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QcyKDTQ772I minuto 8:56

Comment: en la versión 25 puedes usar el componente https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html

Comment: Otra librería https://github.com/ittianyu/BottomNavigationViewEx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eso no es un elemento de android que está en el SDK, según el vídeo que pasas es una librería de **GitHub** en la que en dependencias del graddle tienes que poner compile 'com.roughike:bottom-bar:2.0.2'

Aquí está la librería de [**GitHub**](https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar), sigue los pasos que te indique para poder utilizarla

Comment: Vale, ¿ Has usado alguna vez esto ? He puesto lo de compile y sigue sin ir

Comment: No lo he usado nunca, pero supongo que será seguir los pasos que te indique la página de GitHub del proyecto, si te das cuenta te pone cómo crear listeners, camiarle de color o hacer que se esconda al hacer scroll y mirando en la estructura del proyecto he visto que hay un [ejemplo](https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/bottombar/sample)

Comment: si, lo acabo de ver muchas gracias Joacer! +1!

Comment: de nada!! espero te sirva de ayuda!

Comment: no soy capaz de hacer que me deje usarlo.... necesito ayuda...

Comment: que error te dice? nunca lo he usado voy a probar

Comment: haced un chat y entro, webserveis. El error es que me sale en rojo el mbottomBar

Answer (score 2):

La libreria de soporte 25  `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0` google a intucido de forma nativa el control `BottomNavigationView` ver [documentación oficial](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html).

Su implementación en el layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:menu="@menu/my_navigation_items" />
```

Crear archivo `menu/my_navigation_items.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_history_black_24dp"
        android:title="add" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/delete"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite_black_24dp"
        android:title="delete" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/call"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_place_black_24dp"
        android:title="call" />
</menu>
```

En java para obtener el elemento seleccionado:

```
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation_view);
bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch (id) {
            case R.id.action_history:
                //@todo acción ver historicos
                break;
            case R.id.action_favorite:
                // @todo acción ver favoritos
                break;
            case R.id.action_place:
                // @todo acción ver lugares
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

});
```

**Funcionalidades extras**

Veo que es muy nuevo ese control y Google no le deja hacer demasiada personalización.

- No he encontrado como quitar las etiquetas
- No ser como hacer que en tableta se vea a la izquirda de forma vertical.
- No ser evitar que el efecto ripple se expande fuera del control
- No ser como anclarlo que tenga referencia al cordinatorlayout así ocultarlo con un behavior al realizar scroll.

De momento lo mejor es usar la librería [BottomBar](https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar) que ha recomendado @Joacer

Te dejo unos tutoriales

- [build-android-material-design-bottom-navigation](http://androidgifts.com/build-android-material-design-bottom-navigation/)
- [build-android-material-design-bottom-navigation-part-2](http://androidgifts.com/build-android-material-design-bottom-navigation-part-2/)

Comment: Muy buen aporte, yo estoy trabajando y no he podido investigar mucho sobre el tema, te doy +1!

Comment: Me limita algo si uso los SDK 25 en vez de los 23 ? En 23 hay muchas cosas para descargar en el SDK y en el 25 solo hay 4 contadas...

Comment: si no voy equivocado el 25 es Android 7.1 supongo durante el trimestre irán añadiendo más cosas, si quieres quedarte en la 23 utiliza la librería que te recomienda @joacer

Comment: Esa librería, no sé como ponerla... he puesto eso de compile. .... pero me sigue dando error.

Comment: voy a mirar de implementarla con la versión 23

Comment: De todas formas, voy a seguir mirandolo y comento mas tarde, muchas gracias, si os sale algo avisad compañeros.

Comment: Creo que he conseguido algo... ya veremos que tal me va, si no os diré, por cierto, tengo un texto asignado a cada pestañita pero solo aparece cuando hago click y si clicko en otro se va, ¿ como hago para que se vea siempre? Tengo en el menu esto : item
        android:id="@+id/Cronometro"
        android:icon="@drawable/stopwatch"
        android:title="Cronometro" />